# Getting java.lang.NullPointerException while executing my test case

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

I am new to selenium. Please help me to solve this error.

I am using page object model.

**Below is the page file,**

```java
package com.nielsen.naukri.pages.search;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import com.nielsen.jomapp.pages.home.WelcomePage;
import com.nielsen.jomapp.pages.prd.OneDemTerrainPage;
import com.nielsen.jomapp.pages.proxy.PageObject;
import com.nielsen.jomapp.pages.proxy.PageProvider;

public class Search_naukri_page implements PageObject<Search_naukri_page>{

    private static final Logger LOG = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(OneDemTerrainPage.class);
    public  PageProvider driver;
    private WelcomePage welcomepage;
    WebDriverWait wait;


    @FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id=\"qsb-keyskill-sugg\"]")
    public  WebElement keySkillfield;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//*[@class=\"mb10\"]/a[1]")
    private WebElement updateprofilebutton;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id=\"search-jobs\"]/button")
    private WebElement searchbutton;

    public Search_naukri_page(PageProvider driver2) {
        this.driver = driver2;
    }


    @Override
    public Search_naukri_page navigateTo() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        welcomepage = new WelcomePage(driver).navigateTo();
        return this;
    }

    public void enterkeyskill(String keyskill) {
        System.out.println("In page file keyskill loaded is :" +keyskill);
        //driver.waitForPageFullyLoad();
        PageProvider.implicitlyWaitSeconds(this.driver.getDriver(), 25);
        System.out.println("In page file keyskill loaded is :" +keyskill);
            this.keySkillfield.click();//getting error in this line
            this.keySkillfield.sendKeys(keyskill);
            LOG.debug("Keyskill entered is " +keyskill);
        }

public void updateprofile() {

    LOG.debug("Now in update profile method");
    driver.waitForPageFullyLoad();
        updateprofilebutton.click();
        LOG.debug("Update profile button clicked");
    }

    public void clickSearch() {


        this.searchbutton.click();
        LOG.debug("Search button clicked");
    }




    }
```

**Below is the test file,**

```java
package com.nielsen.naukri.tests.search;

import java.sql.SQLException;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.nielsen.jomapp.pages.home.WelcomePage;
import com.nielsen.jomapp.pages.login.LoginPage;
import com.nielsen.jomapp.pages.prd.OneDemTerrainPage;
import com.nielsen.jomapp.pages.proxy.PageProvider;
import com.nielsen.naukri.pages.search.Search_naukri_page;
import com.nielsen.tests.Production.One_Dem_Terrain;
import com.nielsen.tests.properties.ChosenWebDriver;

public class Search_naukri_test {


    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(One_Dem_Terrain.class);

    private Search_naukri_page search_naukri_page;

    public PageProvider driver;


    @BeforeMethod
    @Parameters({ "browser" })
    public void beforeTest(ChosenWebDriver driverName) {
        this.driver = new PageProvider(driverName.getDriver());
        PageProvider.implicitlyWaitSeconds(this.driver.getDriver(), 5);
        search_naukri_page = new Search_naukri_page(this.driver).navigateTo();
    }


    @AfterMethod
    public void afterTest() {
        this.driver.close();
    }


    @Test(dataProvider = "ParametersProvider", testName = "Search jobs", priority = 1)
    public void SearchJobs(String keyskill)  {



        LOG.debug("Now in @test method");

        PageProvider.implicitlyWaitSeconds(this.driver.getDriver(),25);
        System.out.println("printed" +keyskill);
        search_naukri_page.enterkeyskill(keyskill);
        search_naukri_page.clickSearch();


    }

    @DataProvider(name = "ParametersProvider")
    public static String[][] getDataFromDataProvider() {
        String[][] testData = {
                {"Python"}

                };
        return testData;
    }

}
```

**Below is the error,**

```
FAILED: SearchJobs("Python")
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.nielsen.naukri.pages.search.Search_naukri_page.enterkeyskill(Search_naukri_page.java:48)
    at com.nielsen.naukri.tests.search.Search_naukri_test.SearchJobs(Search_naukri_test.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:86)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:643)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:820)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1128)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:782)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:632)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:366)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:361)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:319)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:268)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1244)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1169)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1064)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't use `PageFactory` to instantiate fields of your `Search_naukri_page`. So they are null and make your code throwing NPE.

Try to add `PageFactory.initElements(driver, this)` as the last line of you constructor like shown below:

```java
public Search_naukri_page(PageProvider driver2) {
    this.driver = driver2;
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this)
}
```

Comment: @MohamedAli You can mark my answer as correct